# Is there a limitation for Dialog's title?

Tags: android

I've created a `DialogFragment` and used `getDialog().setTitle("Application failed to decrypt the file")` and the thing I see in the title is "Application failed to". Is there a limitation for a title? How can I put the whole string in it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know but anyway your title does feel too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMessage%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)  to show a message instead for something this long.

Comment: Agreed. @siik: The title should be short and concise. If you have passed 2-3 words, you have done it wrong. =)

Comment: But folks, there is no setMessage() method for Dialog (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)

Comment: use an alert dialog

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMessage%28java.lang.CharSequence%29